# Album name gets corrupted when characters are Japanese

Tags: unicode, facebook-graph-api

Please let me know the maximum number of "Album Name".

Now I'm developing Photo Upload app with Graph API.
When creating an album, the album name gets corrupted if the number of Japanese characters exceeds 21.
Below is the example of this issue.

e.g.
Input: 
あいうえおかきくけこあいうえおかきくけこあい

Registered Album Name:
あいうえおかきくけこあいうえおかきくけこあ��

Note that the same issue occurs if more than 21 Korean or Chinese characters are set as Album Name.

Comment: Log it here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that there is a length limit on this field. Guessing that they're using UTF-8, it would be a limit of 64 bytes, rather than a integral number of characters.

Facebook appear to be truncating the string at that number of bytes, regardless of whether that byte limit happens to align with a character boundary or not. This kind of misbehaviour is unfortunately common in languages that don't handle text strings as Unicode characters natively. In your case the last `い` takes up three bytes, but there's only room for two, so you get left with two trailing bytes that don't form a valid UTF-8 sequence, hence `��`.

To stop this happening you'd have to do their job for them and impose the length limit in a Unicode-clean way. One way to do this would be to encode to UTF-8 yourself, do the truncation, and convert back to characters ignoring the invalid end bytes. eg in Python:

```
>>> print u'あいうえおかきくけこあいうえおかきくけこあい'.encode('utf-8')[:64].decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
あいうえおかきくけこあいうえおかきくけこあ
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I got the specification and limitation of this issue.
I'll handle this issue by checking the number of bytes.